# Why Laravel uses wrong database file after setting environment?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In `bootstrap/start.php` I have the following:

```php
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    if($myenv = getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')):
        return $myenv;
    else:
        return 'local';
    endif;
});
```

Ok so I setup a local folder and put in a database.php file with my local connections.

Just to make sure its picking up the correct environment I put in the template: `{{ App::environment(); }}`  which outputs `local`.

But when making a DB call its giving me error:  **`Undefined index`**`: DB1_HOST`

My base (production) `database.php` file has:

```php
'host'      => $_SERVER["DB1_HOST"],
'database'  => $_SERVER["DB1_NAME"],
'username'  => $_SERVER["DB1_USER"],
'password'  => $_SERVER["DB1_PASS"],
```

Why is it looking at the production database file?

Comment: Is your file at `app/config/local/database.php`?

Comment: yes correct. if i migrate and use env=local it picks that up!

Comment: Where are you making db calls? If in CLI, you need to specify `--env=local`. Also, considering making your default your local environment and specifying production specially, just so you don't default to production "by accident" ever (since that could, obviously, lead to terrible things happening).

Comment: Won't `$myenv = getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')` always be true? You're assigning the result of `getenv` to `$myenv`.

Comment: Not if 'APPLICATION_ENV' has not been set. Then it would be false and default to local.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel also stores the config information in

```
bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

In some cases it's not updated which may result in wrong database information. Deleting the file should resolve the issue.

Comment: That was my problem, Thank you for posting the solution one year earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use artisan in your terminal and you want to set the environment variable once and for all, you can do :

`export APPLICATION_ENV=local`

And check you current environment using `php artisan env`

Answer (score 1):

Production config files are loaded first and then merged with overrides from other environments. If the production file generates an error (e.g. undefined index) the config loading will bail early without loading the overrides. In the production config file, check the value is set before attempting to use it and the local config file will then load correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the config cache as it may affect

> php artisan config:cache